# Embedded mongodb problems with spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, maven, spring-boot

I am developing a spring application, and I am storing all the data in mLab, so mongoDB. When the application runs, it takes the information from here, but, when trying to test the controllers, services, and repositories, it does not connect, that's why I tried to include embedded mongoDB.
My application properties is (with the data filled):

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=
spring.data.mongodb.host=
spring.data.mongodb.port=37445 
spring.data.mongodb.username=
spring.data.mongodb.password=
```

Then, I have a MongoConfig class that is supposed to be the one used by the tests:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

import cz.jirutka.spring.embedmongo.EmbeddedMongoFactoryBean;

@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {
    private static final String MONGO_DB_URL = "localhost";
    private static final String MONGO_DB_NAME = "test";

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws IOException {
        EmbeddedMongoFactoryBean mongo = new EmbeddedMongoFactoryBean();
        mongo.setBindIp(MONGO_DB_URL);
        MongoClient mongoClient = mongo.getObject();
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, MONGO_DB_NAME);
        return mongoTemplate;
    }
}
```

And the Controller test is:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.redirectedUrl;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

import com.uniovi.Application;

@SpringBootTest(classes = { Application.class })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class OperatorControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private OperatorControllerTest operatorController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(operatorController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testNotLoggedIn() throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = get("/operator/list");
        int status = mockMvc.perform(request).andExpect(redirectedUrl("/login")).andReturn().getResponse().getStatus();
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.FOUND.value(), status);
    }

}
```

The pom.xml has these three dependencies(apart from the others for the rest of the project):

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cz.jirutka.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedmongo-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The problem is that, when executing, I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
>   ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:107)
>   ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
>   ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
>   ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242)
>   ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>   [.cp/:na]     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>   [.cp/:na]     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>   [.cp/:na]     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>   [.cp/:na]     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>   [.cp/:na]     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   [.cp/:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'embeddedMongoServer' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/embedded/EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.io.IOException: Could not start process: failed errno:10049 La
>   dirección solicitada no es válida en este contexto. for socket:
>   34.243.17.210:37445 2018-04-11T19:56:30.505+0200 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.
>   2018-04-11T19:56:30.505+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc:
>   48
>
> at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:138)
>   ~[spring-boot-test-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
>   ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
>   ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]    ... 25 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not start process:
>   failed errno:10049 La dirección solicitada no es válida en este
>   contexto. for socket: 34.243.17.210:37445 2018-04-11T19:56:30.505+0200
>   E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.
>   2018-04-11T19:56:30.505+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc:
>   48
>
> at
>   de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.AbstractMongoProcess.onAfterProcessStart(AbstractMongoProcess.java:79)
>   ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-2.0.0.jar:na]     at
>   de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.AbstractProcess.(AbstractProcess.java:114)
>   ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.process-2.0.1.jar:na]   at
>   de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.AbstractMongoProcess.(AbstractMongoProcess.java:53)
>   ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-2.0.0.jar:na]     at
>   de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodProcess.(MongodProcess.java:50)
>   ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-2.0.0.jar:na]     at
>   de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodExecutable.start(MongodExecutable.java:44)
>   ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-2.0.0.jar:na]     at
>   de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodExecutable.start(MongodExecutable.java:34)
>   ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-2.0.0.jar:na]     at
>   de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Executable.start(Executable.java:101)
>   ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.process-2.0.1.jar:na]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_161]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_161]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_161]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_161]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1835)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   ... 40 common frames
>   omitted

I have already looked all over the internet, and all the different solutions are useless for my code.

Comment: Your embedded db tries to start up at ip address 34.243.17.210, which seems to be an Amazon server in Ireland. Is this what you want to do during your test?

Comment: No, that's not my intention, I think... I mean, I didn't even know about that